# Dispute unauthorized charge on PayPal

Tags: money-transfer, paypal, transaction

I have an unauthorized charge for 500 dollars on my PayPal sent to a random person. I contacted PayPal about this and within 2 hours, they responded that they had thoroughly looked into the case and since this was a personal transaction, they could do nothing. I contacted my bank Wells Fargo and they mentioned they could stop the transaction but only for a fee. What can I do in this case and who should I dispute the charges with?

Comment: How did this happen? Does someone know your username and password?

Comment: How much is the fee? Did Wells Fargo give you a timeline by which you must stop the transaction? If you didn't authorize it, and PayPal isn't helping, I'd probably pay the fee. It's better than nothing and my assumption is if you wait too long you may not be able to reverse the transaction.

Comment: its too late to stop now I believe. Wells Fargo said they would investigate after it goes through. I believe someone may know my username and password but its impossible to say how exactly the transaction occurred.

Comment: I don't think stopping the bank transaction will help you a whole lot, you will still owe paypal the money